# Set nlfilter boundary options

Tags: matlab, filtering

I'm using `nlfilter` function for some specific filter operation (sliding-neighborhood operation). and this function assume that all the values out of the boundries are 0.
I want this values to be symmetric or `NaN`

when using other filter functions like `imfilter` or `medfilt2` it can be set via parameter option, for example: `'symmetric'`,`'replicate'` etc.

Is there a way to to something like that with `nlfilter` (or maybe a different function which I can write specific filtering method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [padarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html) with the same boundary options as `imfilter` and pass the resulting matrix to `nlfilter`. Obviously you'll also have to strip off the boundary from the final matrix.